# Can we use Freetype Text on OpenGL ES 1.0 in Android? Is there any way to use it with just libraries instead of using NDK?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, android-ndk, freetype

I would to render high quality text in OpenGL ES 1.0 and I came to know about freetype. Can I use freetype text on OpenGL ES 1.0/1.1. If yes, are there any java libraries which I use without using NDK for that?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to render the text with the Android framework code (which uses FreeType) into a Bitmap, and then convert the Bitmap to a texture with `texImage2D()`.  Create a Bitmap, create a Canvas for that bitmap, and use methods like `drawText()`.  The text metrics will tell you where the pixels went.

For an example of this, used to generate a bunch of static strings onto a sprite sheet, see [Android Breakout](https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/source/browse/src/com/faddensoft/breakout/TextResources.java).  The screenrecord v1.1 code does something similar, but because it only supports ASCII it just generates 95 glyphs and renders the characters individually.

We're currently up to OpenGL ES 3.1, so it would probably be a good idea to target GLES 2.0 or later.  (The GLES 3 API is a superset of GLES 2, but GLES 1 is significantly different in its basic operation.)